# How to determine if a polynomial is in the range space?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-homomorphism

This question in my textbook asks me to determine if the following polynomial is in the null space and/or range space.

Let $h:P3 \to P4 $ be given by  $p(x) \mapsto x\cdot p(x) $

Is $x^3$ in the null space or range space?

---

I said that it is not in the null space because $h(x^3) = x^4$ is not the zero polynomial of the codomain. But I do not understand how to determine if $x^3$ is in the range space? The book defines the range space of a homomorphism $ h: V \mapsto W $ as $\mathscr{R}(h) = \{h(\overrightarrow{v})|\overrightarrow{v}\in V\}$. My interpretation is that the range space is all vectors of the linear map such that v is part of the vector space. Is that correct?

If someone could please explain the concept of the range space, that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: The range of a function is the set of its values.  $x^3$ is in the range of $h$ because $h(x^2)=x^3$.  For comparison:  $x^3+1$, say, is not in the range of $h$ because there is no polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $≤3$ such that $h(p(x))=x^3+1$.

Comment: ok, got it, thanks! I think I was just confused about the term "range space." but it just means if there is a range (i.e., an output value) then it is in the range space.